# How to compare a "Plan" table against a "Completed" table to match specific rows, and also utilize a 3rd table as a lookup in some cases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm fairly new to SQL and completely self-taught, so I apologize ahead of time!  My situation is we have a table that contains a student's plan of courses they should take for each quarter (table E) and a table of courses a student has actually taken (table R).

TABLE E

```
EMPLID | ID | QTR  | SUBJ    | COURSE_NUM
11111  | 1  | 2213 | HCML    | 325
11111  | 1  | 2213 | HPM     | 340
11111  | 1  | 2215 | CMST    | 330
22222  | 1  | 2213 | ART     | 110
22222  | 1  | 2213 | GENERAL | 1
22222  | 1  | 2213 | GENERAL | 5
```

TABLE R

```
EMPLID | QTR  | SUBJ    | COURSE_NUM
11111  | 2213 | CMST    | 330
11111  | 2213 | HCML    | 325
11111  | 2215 | HPM     | 340
22222  | 2213 | ART     | 105
22222  | 2213 | ENGL    | 201
22222  | 2213 | ASTR&   | 101
```

In table E there can also be placeholder courses listed as "GENERAL" that can map to a large set of courses defined in table G.  So if a student has "GENERAL 1" on their plan, and they take any of the courses in table G marked with a 1, it should count as a match.

TABLE G

```
SUBJ  | NUM | MAPPING
ENGL& | 101 |   1
ENGL  | 201 |   1
ENGL& | 235 |   1
ANTH& | 215 |   5
ASTR& | 101 |   5
BIOL  | 108 |   5
```

I've managed to make the first part work, but I'm completely stuck on how I would do the mapping of these GENERAL courses. Instead of returning PLACEHOLDER in the final column, I want it to show a MATCH or MISMATCH.  Do I do some sort of a conditional join on the other table?

DESIRED RESULTS

```
EMPLID | ID | QTR  | E.SUBJ | E.COURSE_NUM | R.SUBJ | R.COURSE_NUM | FOLLOW_PLAN
11111  | 1  | 2213 | HCML    | 325         | HCML   | 325          | MATCH
11111  | 1  | 2213 | HPM     | 340         | NULL   | NULL         | MISMATCH
11111  | 1  | 2215 | CMST    | 330         | NULL   | NULL         | MISMATCH
22222  | 1  | 2213 | ART     | 110         | NULL   | NULL         | MISMATCH
22222  | 1  | 2213 | GENERAL | 1           | ENGL   | 201          | MATCH
22222  | 1  | 2213 | GENERAL | 5           | ASTR&  | 101          | MATCH
```

Here is a sample of the code I have working now:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE PlanCourses (
>   EMPLID int
>   ,ID int
>   ,QTR int
>   ,SUBJ varchar(7)
>   ,COURSE_NUM int
>   );
>
> INSERT INTO PlanCourses
>   VALUES
>   (11111,1,2213,'HCML',325)
>   ,(11111,1,2213,'HPM',340)
>   ,(11111,1,2215,'CMST',330)
>   ,(22222,1,2213,'ART',110)
>   ,(22222,1,2213,'GENERAL',1)
>   ,(22222,1,2213,'GENERAL',5);
>
> CREATE TABLE CourseWork(
>   EMPLID int
>   ,QTR int
>   ,SUBJ varchar(7)
>   ,COURSE_NUM int
>   );
>   
> INSERT INTO CourseWork
>   VALUES
>   (11111,2213,'CMST',330)
>   ,(11111,2213,'HCML',325)
>   ,(11111,2215,'HPM',340)
>   ,(22222,2213,'ART',110)
>   ,(22222,2213,'ENGL',201)
>   ,(22222,2213,'ASTR&',101);
>
> CREATE TABLE PlaceholderCourse (
>   SUBJ varchar(7)
>   ,NUM int
>   ,MAPPING int);
>   
> INSERT INTO PlaceholderCourse
>   VALUES
>   ('ENGL&',101,1)
>   ,('ENGL',201,1)
>   ,('ENGL&',235,1)
>   ,('ANTH&',215,5)
>   ,('ASTR&',101,5)
>   ,('BIOL',108,5);
> GO
> ```

18 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT * FROM PlanCourses;
> SELECT * FROM CourseWork;
> SELECT * FROM PlaceholderCourse;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> EMPLID | ID |  QTR | SUBJ    | COURSE_NUM
> -----: | -: | ---: | :------ | ---------:
>  11111 |  1 | 2213 | HCML    |        325
>  11111 |  1 | 2213 | HPM     |        340
>  11111 |  1 | 2215 | CMST    |        330
>  22222 |  1 | 2213 | ART     |        110
>  22222 |  1 | 2213 | GENERAL |          1
>  22222 |  1 | 2213 | GENERAL |          5
>
> EMPLID |  QTR | SUBJ  | COURSE_NUM
> -----: | ---: | :---- | ---------:
>  11111 | 2213 | CMST  |        330
>  11111 | 2213 | HCML  |        325
>  11111 | 2215 | HPM   |        340
>  22222 | 2213 | ART   |        110
>  22222 | 2213 | ENGL  |        201
>  22222 | 2213 | ASTR& |        101
>
> SUBJ  | NUM | MAPPING
> :---- | --: | ------:
> ENGL& | 101 |       1
> ENGL  | 201 |       1
> ENGL& | 235 |       1
> ANTH& | 215 |       5
> ASTR& | 101 |       5
> BIOL  | 108 |       5
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>     E.EMPLID
>     ,E.ID
>     ,E.QTR
>     ,E.SUBJ
>     ,E.COURSE_NUM
>     ,R.SUBJ
>     ,R.COURSE_NUM
>     ,CASE 
>         WHEN E.SUBJ = 'GENERAL'
>         THEN 'PLACEHOLDER'
>         WHEN R.SUBJ IS NOT NULL
>         THEN 'Match'
>         ELSE 'Mismatch'
>         END AS FOLLOW_PLAN
>     
> FROM 
>     PLANCOURSES E
>
>     LEFT JOIN COURSEWORK R 
>         ON R.EMPLID = E.EMPLID
>         AND R.QTR = E.QTR
>         AND R.SUBJ = E.SUBJ
>         AND R.COURSE_NUM = E.COURSE_NUM
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> EMPLID | ID |  QTR | SUBJ    | COURSE_NUM | SUBJ | COURSE_NUM | FOLLOW_PLAN
> -----: | -: | ---: | :------ | ---------: | :--- | ---------: | :----------
>  11111 |  1 | 2213 | HCML    |        325 | HCML |        325 | Match      
>  11111 |  1 | 2213 | HPM     |        340 | null |       null | Mismatch   
>  11111 |  1 | 2215 | CMST    |        330 | null |       null | Mismatch   
>  22222 |  1 | 2213 | ART     |        110 | ART  |        110 | Match      
>  22222 |  1 | 2213 | GENERAL |          1 | null |       null | PLACEHOLDER
>  22222 |  1 | 2213 | GENERAL |          5 | null |       null | PLACEHOLDER
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b1fca35e6229719ef0d6dced5691d77e)*

Comment: Please provide the desired results for the provided sample data.

Comment: Sorry about that - I just added!

Comment: What if the student had 2 general 1 items? Would they need to match 2 different rows from table G?

Comment: Also if you provide the sample data as DDL+DML (or a DB Fiddle) you make it much easier for others to assist.

Comment: @slhst52 - Since you're new to S.O. here's an example of what we mean by DDL + DML in the form a fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ebf8d9841c32c57158973b852e6c512f . Play around with it and when you're ready, use the `markdown` link to generate formatted code you can paste into your question.

Comment: @SOS - thanks so much for the pointer, I have included that in the original post now.

Answer (score 0):

First you'll expand the plan against the list of possible general courses. After that you do a conditional join (as you anticipated) based on the matching criteria. Then remove the extra/potential general courses that didn't contribute any actually completions:

```
select *,
    case when r.COURSE_NUM is null then 'MISMATCH' else 'MATCH' end as FOLLOW_PLAN
from
    PLANCOURSES e
    left outer join GENERAL g
        on e.SUBJ = 'GENERAL' and g.MAPPING = e.COURSE_NUM
    left outer join COURSEWORK r    
        on  r.EMPLID = e.EMPLID and r.QTR = e.QTR and (
                e.SUBJ <> 'GENERAL' and r.SUBJ = e.SUBJ and r.COURSE_NUM = e.COURSE_NUM
            or  e.SUBJ  = 'GENERAL' and r.SUBJ = g.SUBJ and r.COURSE_NUM = g.NUM
        )
where (g.NUM is null or r.COURSE_NUM is not null);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=347687771a1d888762d5dfcef8b9e9f0

It sounds like there's a possibility of mapping multiple completed courses on to the same general plan slot. Not sure if that would be an issue.

Assuming that none of the courses numbers correspond to mapping numbers you could collapse the `or` logic in the join condition a little bit. I doubt there's any benefit and the longer version is probably clearer:

```
-- pay attention to the order of the matches
and r.SUBJ       = COALESCE(g.SUBJ, e.SUBJ)
and r.COURSE_NUM = COALESCE(g.NUM,  e.COURSE_NUM)
```

Note also that these are equivalent in case you have a preference:

```
and     (g.NUM is null      or r.COURSE_NUM is not null)
and not (g.NUM is not null and r.COURSE_NUM is null)
```

You can also use `outer apply`:

```
select e.EMPLID, e.ID, e.QTR,
    case when e.SUBJ = 'GENERAL'
        then concat('GENERAL ', cast(e.COURSE_NUM as varchar(2)),
                    concat(' (' + gr.SUBJ + ')', ''))
        else e.SUBJ end as SUBJ,
    coalesce(rr.COURSE_NUM, gr.COURSE_NUM) as COURSE_NUM,
    case when coalesce(rr.COURSE_NUM, gr.COURSE_NUM) is null
        then 'MISMATCH' else 'MATCH' end as FOLLOW_PLAN,
    GMAP_NUM
from
    PLANCOURSES e
    outer apply (
        select r.SUBJ, r.COURSE_NUM,
            row_number() over (
                partition by r.EMPLID, r.QTR, g.MAPPING
                order by r.COURSE_NUM, r.SUBJ) as GMAP_NUM
        from GENERAL g inner join COURSEWORK r
            on  r.SUBJ = g.SUBJ and r.COURSE_NUM = g.NUM        
        where e.SUBJ = 'GENERAL'
            and r.EMPLID = e.EMPLID and r.QTR = e.QTR
            and g.MAPPING = e.COURSE_NUM
    ) gr
    outer apply (
        select r.COURSE_NUM
        from COURSEWORK r
        where e.SUBJ <> 'GENERAL'
            and r.EMPLID = e.EMPLID and r.QTR = e.QTR
            and r.SUBJ = e.SUBJ and r.COURSE_NUM = e.COURSE_NUM
    ) rr
where coalesce(gr.GMAP_NUM, 1) = 1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cbfb7bbddcac7224352a5009c32ab8dc

Comment: thank you - this gets me much closer!  In the case of multiple completed courses matching a plan slot, I would just want to select 1 (and no preference for which). In the case when a match isn't found for a GENERAL, I still want it to appear in the results with a MISMATCH one time.  For instance, if you remove ENGL 201 from the GENERAL table, I would still want the GENERAL 1 line to appear for student 11111.

Comment: @slhst52 It may just make more sense to use `outer apply`. Check out my update.

Comment: thanks again for the help.  A new issue I found is when a student takes a course that applies to more than one of the plan options.  For instance, if a student's plan has MATH 141 on it, and also a GENERAL 2, I would want the math course to only count for the explicit match, and then not count towards the General.  Essentially, I need a way to take courses from the COUREWORK out of the available matches once they have already been matched.  Does that make sense?  Additionally, the Outer Apply is taking a ridiculously long time to run in my database (1+hr).  Any pointers/ideas?

Comment: Updated fiddle with example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c12dec66bd5298a3e426b7c141d50aff

Comment: I'm going to have to look into this more. What about where courses were completed in other quarters even?

Comment: For now we only want to look at courses in the quarter they were planned.

Comment: This seems to work ok. Hopefully these outer applies will work better. You'll have to provide info about table sizes and indexes to offer any help with that problem though. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=4e7b3fb84ca47bfc28cc354f9baa5944

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c8a98c9f3c092c7f258d0dbe397ce9d6